# I want to def a method in a class, to achieve a function

Tags: ruby

i want to complete something like this:

```
class Template
  def initialize(temp_str)
    # come code
  end

  def render options={}
    # some code
  end
end
template = Template.new("{{name}} likes {{animal_type}}")
template.render(name: "John", animal_type: "dogs")
# output: "John likes dogs"
template = Template.new("{{name}} likes {{animal_type}} and  {{animal_type2}}")
template.render(name: "John", animal_type: "dogs", animal_type2: "cats")
# output: "John likes dogs and cats"
```

how should i write the code .. i don't know how to write the `initialize` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, here we don’t need classes. Singleton works fine.

```
module Template
  def render(name:, action: 'likes', **params)
    puts "[DEBUG] parameters passed: #{params.keys.join(', ')}"
    animals = params.values.join(' and ')
    "#{name} #{action} #{animals}"
  end
  module_function :render
end

Template.render(name: 'John', animal_type: 'cats', animal_type2: 'dogs')

#⇒ [DEBUG] parameters passed: animal_type, animal_type2
# "John likes cats and dogs"
```

---

To reinvent a wretched version of handlebars from the scratch, one might do:

```
class Template
  def initialize(template)
    @template = template
  end

  def render(**params)
    @template.gsub(/{{.*?}}/) { |m| params[m[/(?<={{).*(?=}})/].to_sym] }
  end
end
```

Comment: my aim is to replace the arg in the `{{` and `}}` ,and the other part in the string isn't chaged ,so the `likes` is just a placehodler, i also can add some word in the string , such as in the end  `very much`